# Angular.js, $timeout.flush causing infinite digest loop in a directive's unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, timeout, karma-runner

I m trying to write unit tests for my angular application with jasmine and karma.

$timeout.flush causing infinite digest loop in a directive's unit test

Here is my directive code

```
   .directive("myDirective", function($timeout) {
      return {
        link: function(scope) {
          $timeout(function() {
            console.log("myDirective after timeout");
            scope.testNum = 1;
          },1000);
        }
      };
    });
```

Here is the unit test code

```
  describe("Directive: myDirective", function() {
    var scope, element, $timeout;
    beforeEach(function() {
      angular.mock.module("myApp");
      angular.mock.inject(function($compile, $rootScope, _$timeout_) {
        $timeout = _$timeout_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        var directiveElement = angular.element(
          "<my-directive></my-directive>"
        );
        element = $compile(directiveElement)(scope);
        scope.$digest();

      });
    });

    it('should update scope.testNum', function() {
      $timeout.flush();
      expect(scope.testNum).toBe(1);
    });
  });
```

and i got this error

> Chrome 47.0.2526 (Mac OS X 10.10.4) Directive: myDirective should update scope.testNum FAILED     Error: [$rootScope:infdig]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
>
> at Error (native)
>
> at web/public/javascripts/lib/angular.min.js:6:416
>
> at r.$digest (web/public/javascripts/lib/angular.min.js:131:499)
>
> at r.$apply (web/public/javascripts/lib/angular.min.js:134:78)
>
> at Object.fn (web/public/javascripts/lib/angular.min.js:146:449)
>
> at Function.self.defer.flush (web/public/javascripts/lib/angular-mocks.js:126:32)
>
> at Function.$delegate.flush (web/public/javascripts/lib/angular-mocks.js:1750:20)
>
> at Object. (web/test/unit/mainSpecs/myDirectiveSpec.js:35:16)

Comment: The name of the test in the error is `should log after timeout `, while the one you posted is `should update scope.testNum`. Are these the same?

Comment: Yes, these are the same, and I updated error text.